# What is the proper way to write a function with different signatures?

Tags: matlab

I would like to write a function that takes as input arguments a *finite* list of parameters and returns another list of output parameters. Alternatively, that function should take one single argument, an array containing the necessary parameters, and return another array containing the output parameters. Finally the function should work with all the combinations of input and output and throw an error otherwise.
**Note:** The parameters, both input and output, are all of the same type (`double`).

For example, consider the following function:

```
function [e, f, g, h] = example( a, b, c, d )

if nargin == 1
    input = a;             % I rename `a` for clarity
    a = input(1);
    b = input(2);
    c = input(3);
    d = input(4);
end

% Generate e, f, g, h from a, b, c, d

if nargout == 1
    output = [e, f, g, h]; % I work with `output` for clarity, but the output
    e = output;            % variable is `e`
end

end
```

I would like to call it as:

```
[e, f, g, h] = example(a, b, c, d)
[e, f, g, h] = example(input)
output = example(a, b, c, d)
output = example(input)
```

where

```
input = [a, b, c, d]
output = [e, f, g, h]
```

So, what is the proper way to define a function with different "signatures"? I feel the way I implemented it could be largely improved.

Comment: That's basically the way that you have to do it.

Comment: use varargin/varargout variables.